# Updating redux store after component props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm wondering what the best approach to handle this scenario is in redux and if theres any patterns to favour or avoid:

I have a 'shopping list' component that is comprised of several sub items, each of which can be modified in a variety of ways. I'm also keeping track of the total price of the shopping list which changes every time a sub item is added, removed or modified as well as other factors.

Currently I have a 'Total' component which is subscribed to the store and recalculates the total when any shopping list items (passed to it as  props) change. This then saves the recalculated total to the store. Whilst this  works and is seemingly more robust than trying to anticipate every action that has an effect on the total, it does mean that the app re-renders twice: firstly when an item changes, then secondly when the total is recalculated.

I'm presuming that this is probably not the best approach to the situation and I'm wondering if I can do something a bit neater directly in the shopping list reducer or using some kind of middleware. Any advice would be appreciated.

-

The current process can be summarised as:

- User modifies shopping list item
- Action is dispatched, updating the store with the modified shopping list
- New state propagates through app
- Price Total component receives new props, recalculates total and dispatches updated total to the store
- New state propagates through app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you're using the Total component to calculate the total and then dispatch an action to update the total in the store is what's complicating things. Your total is actually just a derivation of other parts of your state, and does not need to be stored in the state itself.

Assuming you're using [react-redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux) to connect your Total component to your state, you can simply calculate the total in the mapStateToProps part of your connect(). For example:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    total: state.shoppingList.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price, 0)
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Total)
```

(This example assumes `state.shoppingList` is an array of items, each with a `price` property. Your situation is probably a little more complex, but the idea is the same.)

This would allow your Total component to access/display the total, but without any of the added complication of having to re-update the state.

For improved performance in these state derivations, have a look at [reselect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reselect). It allows you to create "memoized" selectors that will only perform their re-calculations when the relevant parts of state have changed, otherwise they will return the derived value from memory. These selectors can be imported anywhere, so it would make it easy to display the total in other places too, if you ever needed to.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense and definitely sounds like what I should be doing. I think my assumption that storing the calculated value is preferable to calculating it on the fly is what was tripping me up – reselect looks like it will solve most of the things that lead to that assumption in the first place too.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly i think you should use the component will update function :

```
void componentWillReceiveProps(
  object nextProps
)
```

Quote from the official doc :

> "Invoked when a component is receiving new props. This method is not
>   called for the initial render.
>
> Use this as an opportunity to react to a prop transition before
>   render() is called by updating the state using this.setState(). The
>   old props can be accessed via this.props. Calling this.setState()
>   within this function will not trigger an additional render."

This means that when a modification is made to your shopping list, you can calculate the total in the componentWillReceiveProps function without triggering a second render.

Comment: Thanks Hugo. This makes sense although I'm needing to save the recalculated total back to the store after which is triggering the second render.

Comment: well i might i ve missed some informations when i first read your post sry for that. Is your Total component present in different component?

Btw, if your total component is the only component that is linked to the total stored in your store, it would be the only component updated, not the whole application. (Only your Total component render function would be called)

Comment: No problem, I actually updated it slightly to make it a bit clearer. Yes the total is used in other areas of the app which is why it needs to go back into the store to then propagate through to various other components.

Comment: Well since you need to update the store, you ll always have a render from the modification of your shopping list and then a render of all the Total components currently mounted when you recalculate the total and i don't think there is anything wrong with that.

The only way you could prevent two renders is to pass your shopping list to your Total component instead of the total present in the store. You could calculate the total from your shopping list and avoid a re render when the total is send to the store (or you could remove the total from your store if you don't need it elsewhere)